# Verificar si una cadena es alfanumérica en python

Tags: python, python-3.9

me encuentro practicando un poco de python y desarrollando algunos ejercicios que me he encontrado en internet, necesito saber si existe algún método para poder evaluar si mi cadena ingresada por un usuario es alfanumérica.

Este es el codigo que me encuentro desarrollando de momento con una validación anteriormente  que se pide en el ejercicio.

```py
while True:
    nombreDeUsuario = input('Por favor, ingrese un nombre de usuario')
    if len(nombreDeUsuario) < 6 or len(nombreDeUsuario) > 12:
        print('Por favor procure que su nombre de usuario contenga un mínimo de 6 caracteres y un máximo de 12 caracteres')
```

Primero se me pedía que restringiera al usuario a ingresar un nombre con un mínimo de 5 caracteres y un máximo de 12. Acepto todo tipo de ayuda o críticas, muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes usar el método `.isalnum()`

Comment: lo utilicé pero creo que lo hice mal, buscaré la documentación para ver cómo se utiliza.

Comment: te voy a dar una respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer con el método `.isalnum()` el cual verifica si la cadena es una cadena alfanumérica, solo que no valida los espacios, si tu cadena contiene un espacio retorna `False`

```py
while True:
    nombreDeUsuario = input('Por favor, ingrese un nombre de usuario')
    if not 5 < len(nombreDeUsuario) < 12 and nombreDeUsuario.isalnum():
        print('Por favor procure que su nombre de usuario contenga un mínimo de 6 caracteres y un máximo de 12 caracteres')
```